# Foundation Zurb & Top bar does not appear

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm kind of new to Foundation and I'm trying to create a top bar, but my code does not create the top bar for me. Can you help??? I've reviewed the documentation for the top bar, but I'm still stuck.

Thank you in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="meduim-6 columns"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100"></div>

    </div>-->
    <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
      <nav class="top-bar" >

      </nav>
    </div>



    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
  <!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->

  <script>
    $(document).foundation({

  topbar : {
    custom_back_text: false,
    is_hover: false,
    mobile_show_parent_link: true
  }
});
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.css and app.js are missing

```
<head>
  <!-- Included CSS Files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">

  <!-- Custom Modernizr -->
  <script src="javascripts/foundation/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- JS Files-->
  <script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where can I find the app.js and app.css files? I'm using Foundation 5.

Comment: no you dont need app.css or app.js (this is for scss version of foundation) he is using css version from the looks of it..